# macro for simulating access two dimensional array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, opencl

OpenCL only offers access to single dimensional arrays using the C99 specs.  My problem however is in two dimensions and I am using two dimensional arrays on the host side

Rather than making my code less readable by calculating indices, I would like to use a C macro to get element `A[i][j]`.  Unfortunately I'm rather bad at this and have little experience in C. I think I have the general idea of how it is done, but if someone could critique it would be appreciated.

It would be something like:

```
#define 2d_access(u, y, x) (u[y][x])
```

where u is the matrix, y is the row, and x is the column and the macro would return the 
value at `u[y][x]`

The matrix is allocated statically so the macro would have a WIDTH component.

```
#define 2d_access(u, y, x) (u[y * WIDTH] + x])
```

Answer (score 8):

Since all the answers so far rely on a constant width, here's a (heavyweight) solution for arbitrary width columns:

```
#define matrix_type(t) struct { size_t width; t array[]; }

#define matrix_alloc(t, w, h) malloc(offsetof(matrix_type(t), array[(w) * (h)]))

#define matrix_init(m, t, w, h) \
  matrix_type(t) *m = matrix_alloc(t, w, h); \
  if(!m) matrix_alloc_error(); else m->width = (w);

#define matrix_index(m, w, h) m->array[m->width * (w) + (h)]

// redefine if you want to handle malloc errors
#define matrix_alloc_error()
```

Just deallocate the array with `free`.

Of course, you can add a field for height as well and do bounds checking, among other things. You could even write these as actual functions, or use a macro to automatically declare `struct` types so you don't have to use an anonymous `struct` type for everything. If you need it on the stack, you could use `alloca` at the cost of portability.

If you have a constant matrix size, you can use some casting hacks to achieve "native" 2D indexing (via the `[]` operator):

```
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)

#define MANGLE(x) CAT(x, _hidden_do_not_use_0xdeadbeef_)

#define matrix_init(m, t, w, h) \
  t MANGLE(m)[(w) * (h)]; \
  t (*m)[(w)] = (void *)MANGLE(m);

// because of the funky typing, `m[0][1]` does what you'd expect it to.
```

Note that, unlike the other solution, this creates a second variable, which is probably not very clean, but I think I used a pretty clear mangling method so it won't get in the way in practice.

Comment: Thanks not not polluting the Internet with hardcoded solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Even cleaner would be to define a macro for each array you're using, so you can make it look exactly like a 2D array access. So, given the array `A`, you would define:

```
#define A(r, c) (A[(r)*WIDTH + (c)])
```

Note the parentheses around the substituted values. This handles cases where the substitution is an expression, like `A(i + 1, j)`. Without the parentheses, this would expand to `A[i + 1*WIDTH + j]`, which is not what you want:

```
A[i + 1*WIDTH + j] = A[WIDTH + i + j] != A[(i + 1)*WIDTH + j]
```

In order to avoid the same problem with the second argument, both are enclosed in parentheses in the substitution text.

Comment: Quick question, is it safe to use the same name `A` in the macro name and expansion? From a quick test it looks it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

No critique, you already gave the solution:

```
#define access_2d(u, y, x) (u[(y) * WIDTH + (x)])
```

OK, maybe I think differently, but I would define it as

```
// x before y
#define access_2d(u, x, y) (u[(y) * WIDTH + (x)])
```

That is not better, though, just a preference.

Comment: This only works if all your arrays have a constant width, which may defeat the point of using 2D arrays.

Comment: If the different arrays have different widths it may be worth to encapsulate them into a `struct` containing the pointer and the width, and changing the macro so that it operates on said `struct`.

Comment: @Matteo - That's actually what I just wrote up for an answer.

Comment: I assumed that WIDTH is a constant. Looks like it.

Comment: @Chris: Why would 2D arrays with a fixed width be pointless? ISTM that 2D arrays with a fixed width and height (e.g. a 4x4 matrix for geometrical transformations) can even be useful, depending on the problem.

Comment: @Rudy - I suppose it's not pointless. It's just that, for a fixed width, you could achieve 2D indexing via the `[]` operator with `type arr[w * h] = {0}; type (*ptr)[w] = (void *)arr;` which, admittedly, looks hairy, but could be hidden behind a macro.